# Using shrine how can I convert all image uploads to jpegs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shrine

Using the gem [shrine](https://shrinerb.com/) (3.4.0) in RoR I have a hack to convert all image uploads to jpegs, but it uses a deprecated plugin that will be remove in Shrine 4.

```
class ImageUploader < Shrine
  # Converts all images to jpegs
  process(:store) do |io, context|
    original = io.download
    mime_type = context.try(:[], :record)&.file_data.try(:[], "metadata").try(:[], "mime_type")

    if mime_type != "image/jpeg" || mime_type != "image/jpg"
      # How can we force transparent backgrounds to save as white and not black?
      jpeg = ImageProcessing::Vips
               .source(original)
               .convert("jpeg")
               .saver(quality: 85)
               .call

      original.close

      jpeg
    else
      original.close

      io
    end
  end
end
```

Works but gives me:

```
SHRINE DEPRECATION WARNING: The processing plugin is deprecated and will be removed in Shrine 4. If you were using it with versions plugin, use the new derivatives plugin instead.
```

Any other way to accomplish the same thing? or another plugin I could use?